# How can I avoid duplicate SQL queries with Django model forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following models:

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Models):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
```

and a generic CreateView

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

urlpatterns += [
    path("", CreateView.as_view(model=models.Article, fields="__all__"))
]
```

with the following template (article_form.html)

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ form }}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I am using [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/) to list the performed SQL queries for each web request.

**My question is:** Why is the following SQL query for the author list performed *twice* for each request? And how can I avoid the duplicate query?

```
SELECT "myapp_author"."id", "myapp_author"."name" FROM "myapp_author"
```

Moreover, the debug toolbar says that the first query took only 0.5 ms, whereas the second took 42 ms! Almost 100x longer. How can this be?

I am using Django 3.2 with an SQLite database.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it requesting twice on `POST` request?

Comment: I get the duplicate query on the GET request. When I submit a POST request, the author list should not have to be queried. For completeness: I get three queries from the POST request: two SELECTs for the specific author I selected, and the INSERT INTO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further investigation of the issue, I found that the SQL queries can also be logged to console by configuring [LOGGING](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) appropriately:

settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

This revealed that the SELECT query was in fact only performed once, as it should be. So the error must be in the Debug Toolbar falsely reporting it twice.